# how to extract the fields from this

Tags: java

Additional Text:

```
RCA: CIMD/SMPP - Connection Down - SDC - 140 - MUM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALARM_ID    | EVENT_TIME                | NODE_NAME     | SPECIFIC_PROBLEM  | ADDITIONAL_INFO 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
89403|2015-05-14 04:15:01|MUM_SDC_APP_MUMSMSRAPP1_10.6.227.2|CIMD Session_SR,xxx_140_sr: 3,4:15 AM 5/14/15; 
88143|2015-05-13 03:40:04|MUM_SDC_APP_VS-MUM-SMSR3_10.44.78.4|MO-AT_Queue|MO-AT_Queue,Shortcode_56070: n/aShortcode_140: n/aShortcode_55444: 
n/aShortcode_321: n/aShortcode_139: n/aShortcode_50123: n/aShortcode_1900: 
n/aShortcode_54045: n/aShortcode_55435: n/aShortcode_111: n/aShortcode_144: 
n/aShortcode_52425: n/aShortcode_52586: n/aShortcode_1901: n/a,3:40 AM 5/13/15;
```

Comment: what fields? please, be more specific and tell us what you have tried

Comment: This is fairly ugly input text, but it should be possible to extract what you want.  However, you need to articulate this to us first.

Comment: I am trying to extract MUM_SDC_APP_MUMSMSRAPP1 and MUM_SDC_APP_VS-MUM-SMSR3

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing the data you listed in your question (a file, a SQL database, or a memory object)?

If this were simply formatted text that you stored in a String[], you may want to consider using the split method. It allows you to pull out specific pieces of information by using a regex to act as a delimiter. You may need to get a little creative with your implementation. However, this is only if you stored it as a memory object. The process is slightly more involved for a database record or file.

[Split String Method Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)

Comment: yes I am stroring it in a memory object, but how to deal with 2 delimeter in a single split

Comment: You may need to split it more than once. Check out the link I provided. It will help you.

Comment: will this work???      String Str1 = new String("");

      System.out.println("Return Value :" );
      for (String retval: Str1.split("------", 3)){
         System.out.println(retval);
      }  
  
   String str2 = str1[2];
   String[] parts = Str2.split("\\;");
   for(int i=0; i < parts.length(); i++){
         System.out.println(parts[i]);
  }
   String str3 = parts[2];
   String[] parts0 = Str2.split("\\|");
   System.out.println(parts0[1]);

Comment: where String Str1 = new String("CONTAINS VALUE AFTER Additional Text = " till the END");

Comment: If you are in control of the writing of the file I would get rid of all of that strange formatting first. All of those dashes can be implemented in a method somewhere. If you can't and its someone else's file then I would say you are on the right track. If you only need the information on the bottom then I was say stick with: for (String retval: Str.split("\\|")){...} This will pull the heading values, but you can use that store that for formatting your output.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am guessing the extraction involves values for ALARM_ID, EVENT_TIME,       NODE_NAME, SPECIFIC_PROBLEM, ADDITIONAL_INFO.
If that is correct the solution involves a List> where in you will have to read the file and iterate through it read every row into a map and putting that map into the list
Kindly let me know if this helps or if further help is required condition to you have applied some effort.